# Passing post data back after OpenIdConnectAuthentication callback (signin-oidc) event

Tags: openid-connect, identityserver4

The entry point of my web app requires some post data.  It needs those post data back during the callback from the IdentityServer4 (the signin-oidc callback).

Is the AuthenticationProperties to right place to store the post data?

This is the workflow I plan:

1. During the OpenIdConnectEvents's OnRedirectToIdentityProvider event,
   store the post data in the AuthenticationProperties
2. After the authentication, at the OnTokenResponseReceived event, get back the
   post data from the AuthenticationProperties and put it in the 
   HttpContext.
3. In the controller, if the post data does not exist, check the
   HttpContext for them.

Is it the right approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of post data do you want to access?

Comment: Does it matter what kind of data I need to post?   

It can be a custom 3rd party token and/or token type that the IS4 can use to talk to a 3rd party Identity Provider to do the logon so that it won't need to show the logon dialog.